# Hide Row in DataGridView with Binding not working in my project

Tags: c#, collections, datagridview

I'm facing one problem regarding DataGridView row hiding in my project.
The code I've pasted works in a separate test project, but not in my project. Please help me on this.

The code I'm testing

```
public partial class frmTestGirdBinding : Form
{
    CustomDataCollection cdata = new CustomDataCollection();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public frmTestGirdBinding()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmTestGirdBinding_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = cdata;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        //bindingSource1.Filter = "Srno = 3"; not working


        CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[bindingSource1.DataSource];
        cm.SuspendBinding();
        //InVisible the rows
        dataGridView1.Rows[2].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Rows[3].Visible = false;
        cm.ResumeBinding();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cdata.Count; i++)
        {
            cdata[i].Reading = (float)rnd.NextDouble();
        }
        dataGridView1.Refresh(); //without this all rows are not updating
    }
}

class CustomDataCollection : BindingList<CustomData>
{
    public CustomDataCollection()
    {
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 1, Name = "A", Reading = 11.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 2, Name = "B", Reading = 22.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 3, Name = "C", Reading = 33.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 4, Name = "D", Reading = 44.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 5, Name = "E", Reading = 55.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 6, Name = "F", Reading = 66.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 7, Name = "G", Reading = 77.11F });
    }
}
class CustomData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int srno;

    public int SrNo
    {
        get { return srno; }
        set { srno = value; OnPropertyChanged("SrNo"); }
    }

    string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    float reading;

    public float Reading
    {
        get { return reading; }
        set { reading = value; OnPropertyChanged("Reading"); }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching on this issue solve the problem by adding **DataBindingComplete** event and hide the specific row. DataBindingComplete is fired 2 times, 1 at the time of binding and 2nd after form_load event complete.

```
public partial class frmTestGirdBinding : Form
{
    CustomDataCollection cdata = new CustomDataCollection();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public frmTestGirdBinding()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete);
    }

    private void frmTestGirdBinding_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = cdata;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;            

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cdata.Count; i++)
        {
            cdata[i].Reading = (float)rnd.NextDouble();
        }
        dataGridView1.Refresh(); //without this all rows are not updating
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        //InVisible the rows
        dataGridView1.Rows[2].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Rows[3].Visible = false;
    }
}

class CustomDataCollection : BindingList<CustomData>
{
    public CustomDataCollection()
    {
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 1, Name = "A", Reading = 11.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 2, Name = "B", Reading = 22.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 3, Name = "C", Reading = 33.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 4, Name = "D", Reading = 44.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 5, Name = "E", Reading = 55.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 6, Name = "F", Reading = 66.11F });
        this.Add(new CustomData() { SrNo = 7, Name = "G", Reading = 77.11F });
    }
}
class CustomData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int srno;

    public int SrNo
    {
        get { return srno; }
        set { srno = value; OnPropertyChanged("SrNo"); }
    }

    string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    float reading;

    public float Reading
    {
        get { return reading; }
        set { reading = value; OnPropertyChanged("Reading"); }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```